# it seems `ESC[2J` just scrolls page instead of actually clearing screen, is there an ansi escape sequence that actually clears screen?

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to develop a Linux CLI game in C. Here is part of the code

```
int main(){
    while(1){
    printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");
    printf("\e[?25l");
    printf("* *\n* *\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    usleep(300000);
    printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");
    printf("\e[?25l");
    printf("* * *\n* * *\n* * *\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    usleep(300000);
    }
}
```

it is supposed to repeat the following steps

```
clear screen 
print a small square
clear screen 
print a bigger square
```

it actually does

```
scroll a new page 
print a small square
scroll a new page
print a bigger square
```

and results in a scrollbar and loads of pages, which needs to be removed, how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: You should probably use something like [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), which solves all these problems for you, and will work on different terminal types. Most text-based games on Linux/Unix use that (or one of its predecessors).

Comment: That's the VT100 sequence that "erases the screen with the background colour and moves the cursor to home". (From [this VT100 escape code reference](https://www2.ccs.neu.edu/research/gpc/VonaUtils/vona/terminal/vtansi.htm)) However, note that different modern terminals might not be 100% VT100 compatible, or that they implement it in a way that was used on VT100, but can't be used because of modern things like the scrollbar. Have you checked your terminals emulation settings?

Comment: You could try `ESC[c` to reset the terminal... This may be a sledgehammer option...

Comment: Answer -- Not really. The `\esc[2J` function essentially just outputs a screen worth of newline characters to give you a blank screen. You can however actually clear the contents with a combination of cursor position moves, e.g. `\est[<n>A` up or `\esc[<n>B` down where `<n>` is the number of lines to move (default `1`) and `\esc[2K` (erase whole line)